# S3A hadoop aws jar always return AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

Could anyone please help me in figure out why do I get below exception? All I'm trying to read some data from local file in my spark program and writing into S3. **I have correct secret key and access key specified like this** -

Do you think it's related to version mismatch of some library?

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    // add more spark related properties

    AWSCredentials credentials = DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance().getCredentials();

    conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId());
    conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", credentials.getAWSSecretKey());
```

The java code is plain vanilla -

```
protected void process() throws JobException {
    JavaRDD<String> linesRDD = _sparkContext.textFile(_jArgs.getFileLocation());

    linesRDD.saveAsTextFile("s3a://my.bucket/" + Math.random() + "final.txt");
```

This is my code and gradle.

**Gradle**

```
ext.libs = [
    aws:    [
        lambda: 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.0',
        // The AWS SDK will dynamically import the X-Ray SDK to emit subsegments for downstream calls made by your
        // function
        //recorderCore: 'com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core:1.1.2',
        //recorderCoreAwsSdk: 'com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk:1.1.2',
        //recorderCoreAwsSdkInstrumentor: 'com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-instrumentor:1.1.2',
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
        javaSDK: 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.311',

        recorderSDK: 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.311',
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events
        lambdaEvents: 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:2.0.2',
        snsSDK: 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:1.11.311',
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-emr
        emr :'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:1.11.311'

    ],
    //jodaTime: 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7',
    //guava   : 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0',
    jCommander : 'com.beust:jcommander:1.71',
    //jackson: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:2.8.8',

    jackson: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.0',
    apacheCommons: [
            lang3: "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2",
    ],
    spark: [
            core: 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.0',
            hadoopAws: 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.1',
            //hadoopClient:'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.8.1',
            //hadoopCommon:'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.1',
            jackson: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:2.8.8'
    ],
```

**Exception**

```
2018-04-10 22:14:22.270 | ERROR |  |  |  |c.f.d.p.s.SparkJobEntry-46 
Exception found in job for file type : EMAIL
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://my.bucket/0.253592564392344final.txt: getFileStatus on 
s3a://my.bucket/0.253592564392344final.txt: 
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: 
Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 
62622F7F27793DBA; S3 Extended Request ID: BHCZT6BSUP39CdFOLz0uxkJGPH1tPsChYl40a32bYglLImC6PQo+LFtBClnWLWbtArV/z1SOt68=), S3 Extended Request ID: BHCZT6BSUP39CdFOLz0uxkJGPH1tPsChYl40a32bYglLImC6PQo+LFtBClnWLWbtArV/z1SOt68=
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:158) ~[hadoop-aws-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:101) ~[hadoop-aws-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1568) ~[hadoop-aws-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:117) ~[hadoop-aws-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1436) ~[hadoop-common-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.exists(S3AFileSystem.java:2040) ~[hadoop-aws-2.8.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:131) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.assertConf(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:283) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:71) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
```

Comment: I had a similar kind of issue. For me it was that I did not had the access to the s3 folder. After the access issues were resolved , I could easily access the files in s3.

Answer (score -2):

Once you are playing with Hadoop `Configuration` classes, you need to strip out the `spark.hadoop` prefix, so just use `fs.s3a.access.key`, etc.

All the options are defined in the class `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Constants`: if you reference them you'll avoid typos too.

One thing to consider is all the source for spark and hadoop is public: there's nothing to stop you taking that stack trace, setting some breakpoints and trying to run this in your IDE. It's what we normally do ourselves when things get bad.

Comment: thanks! I'm not playing with Hadoop conf, and that's why I have spark.hadoop prefix. These credential are actually picked up and then failed. I have debugged internals already. It may be a permission issue but I haven't been able to figure out yet. I will post my findings later today. thank you!

Comment: I just went ahead and modified my question showing explicity that 'conf' is a SparkConf object and not HadoopConfiguration. Sorry for the confusion.